# Filtering using dplyr with column names and conditions as strings

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I try to write a simple function to filter a data.frame. The column names and filter conditions are both stored as strings:

```
vars <- c("manufacturer", "engine")
cond <- c("EMBRAER", "Turbo-fan")
```

The output should be the same as the output obtained by the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

nycflights13::planes %>%
  filter(
    .data[[vars[[1]]]] == cond[[1]],
    .data[[vars[[2]]]] == cond[[2]]
  )
```

What is the way to do this using dplyr+purrr? The length of both strings are much longer in reality.

Comment: Depending on your larger workflow, maybe you could instead make a data frame of conditions and use that to do a semi-join with your data, so that you only keep the rows of data that match rows in your conditions data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way to think about this is that you have a dataset of conditions that you want to use for filtering your main data. Create a small data frame of the conditions and their respective variable names, then reshape it into a data frame where those variable names are the column names. Then use `semi_join` to keep just the rows of data that have matching combinations of variables and conditions in the conditions data frame.

```r
vars <- c("manufacturer", "engine")
cond <- c("EMBRAER", "Turbo-fan")

library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

cond_df <- data.frame(vars, cond) %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = vars, value = cond)

nycflights13::planes %>%
  semi_join(cond_df, by = vars)
#> # A tibble: 298 x 9
#>    tailnum  year type        manufacturer model  engines seats speed engine
#>    <chr>   <int> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
#>  1 N10156   2004 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  2 N10575   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  3 N11106   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  4 N11107   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  5 N11109   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  6 N11113   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  7 N11119   2002 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  8 N11121   2003 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#>  9 N11127   2003 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#> 10 N11137   2003 Fixed wing… EMBRAER      EMB-1…       2    55    NA Turbo…
#> # … with 288 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) sym**  - We can convert to `sym`bols and `eval`uate (`!!`).  The `[[` is used mainly for extracting `list` elements.  As the OP showed both 'vars' and 'cond' as `vector`s `[` is enough for extracting each element

```
nycflights13::planes %>%
   filter(
    !!rlang::sym(vars[1]) == cond[1],
     !!rlang::sym(vars[2]) == cond[2]
  )
```

---

**2) parse_expr-** An option is create an expression with `paste` or `str_c` from `stringr` and then parse that expression

```
expr1 <- str_c(vars, str_c('"', cond, '"'), sep="==", collapse=" & ")
nycflights13::planes %>%
    filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(expr1))
# A tibble: 298 x 9
#   tailnum  year type                    manufacturer model     engines seats speed engine   
#   <chr>   <int> <chr>                   <chr>        <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <chr>    
# 1 N10156   2004 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 2 N10575   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145LR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 3 N11106   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 4 N11107   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 5 N11109   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 6 N11113   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 7 N11119   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 8 N11121   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 9 N11127   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
#10 N11137   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# … with 288 more rows
```

---

**3) map2/reduce -** If we have more than one column, then we could use `filter_at`, but here the  'cond' are different.  So, one option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(vars, cond, ~ nycflights13::planes %>%
                       transmute(ind = !! rlang::sym(.x) == .y) %>%
                       pull(ind)) %>%
     reduce(`&`) %>%
     filter(nycflights13::planes, .)
# A tibble: 298 x 9
#   tailnum  year type                    manufacturer model     engines seats speed engine   
#   <chr>   <int> <chr>                   <chr>        <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <chr>    
# 1 N10156   2004 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 2 N10575   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145LR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 3 N11106   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 4 N11107   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 5 N11109   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 6 N11113   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 7 N11119   2002 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 8 N11121   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# 9 N11127   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
#10 N11137   2003 Fixed wing multi engine EMBRAER      EMB-145XR       2    55    NA Turbo-fan
# … with 288 more rows
```